# AX2009: Workflow, how to debug remotely AX32SERV using VS?

Tags: debugging, axapta, remote-debugging, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I want to debug remotely proces of ax32serv.

in **Microsoft Dynamicts AX Sever Configuration Utility**:

- Enable breakpoint to debug x++ code running on this server (is checked)
- Enable global breakpoints to debug x++ code running in batch jobs (is checked)

  1. On server i install **MS remote debugger** (rtool x64) and run it
  2. On my desktop i wos runed **VS 2013** (Shell Integrated)
  3. I select options of server and server proces and attach to process
     on server in MS remote debugger display message about sukcess of connect

[image]

4. I run workflow with breakpoint and VS2013 show nothing.
5. Another I set a code type of workflow and I got error:

   > Unable to attach to the proces. The debugger is not properly installed. Cannot debug the requested type of code. Run setup to install or repair the debugger.

[image]

What I do wrong?

Sorry for my bad English :(

Comment: Did you try to install or repair the debugger?

Comment: Ax debugger is instaled on server and on desktop.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do debugging of AX server.

For AX 2012 it should all [be covered here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/da-dk/library/gg860898.aspx).
For AX 2009, try the following links depending on your senario.

[Debug X++ on EP pages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa629010(v=ax.50).aspx)
[Debug AIF services](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/axsupport/2011/01/19/debugging-aif-web-services/)
...

That said there are several prerequisites, such as permission etc. so it is not for the light harded.